# How to Insert slashes into a string?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a birth date number in the format: 890520, so yy/mm/dd.
However, I need to display it separated by slashes, eg. 89/05/20

How can I do this, as there is no delimiter with which I can split the string?

Comment: So you're asking how to get a substring? `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

Comment: For dates, there's a Java API in the standard library

Comment: Harshal's answer will work, but I _really_ encourage you to treat dates as Dates, not Strings. You can turn your "890520" into a `java.util.Date` object by parsing it with a [`SimpleDateFormat.parse(string)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) such as `DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd"); Date d = parser.parse("890520");` then you can use the full power of date formatting to display it as you like ... 89/05/20, or 20-May-1989, or any number of other ways. Also, now you have a _Date_ that can be used for computations.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, will use that in the future, but this date was purely for cosmetics and didn't need to be used or computed in any manner, so not being an integer doesn't have an impact on my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String a = "890520";
System.out.println(a.substring(0, 2) + "/" + a.substring(2, 4) + "/" + a.substring(4));
```

[substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much! It's been a while since I used substring and I completely overcomplicated it